# Sequelize findAll is not a function

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, passport.js, sequelize.js

I'm making a project with Sequelize and I'm stucked in this step. The problem is that when I try to log in and the passport-local code is executed, **when it reaches the User.findAll(...) it throws that findAll is not a function**.

If I make console.log(User) it shows [function].

My structure:

- /config/config.js
- /config/passport.js
- /models/index.js
- /models/nuke_users.js  (generated by [sequelize-auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto))
- /index.js

config.js:

```
//Setting up the config
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('rocarenav2', 'root', '123456', {
   host: "localhost",
   port: 3306,
   dialect: 'mysql'
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

passport.js:

```
// config/passport.js

// load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// load up the user model
var User            = require('../models/nuke_users');

var crypto          = require('crypto');

function hashPasswordForNuke(password) {
    return md5password =        crypto.createHash('md5').update(password).digest('hex');
}

// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport) {

// =========================================================================
// passport session setup ==================================================
// =========================================================================
// required for persistent login sessions
// passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, {})
    .then(function (user) {
        done(err, user);
    })
    .catch(function (error){
        done(error);
    });
});



// =========================================================================
// LOCAL LOGIN =============================================================
// =========================================================================
// we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
// by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
    User.findAll({
        where: {
            'user_email': email
        }
    }).then(function (user) {
        if(!user)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

        // if the user is found but the password is wrong
        if ((user.user_password).localeCompare(hashPasswordForNuke(password)) === -1)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

        return done(null, user);
    })
    .catch(function (error){
        done(error);
    });

}));

};
```

models/index.js

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config');
var db        = {};

//Create a Sequelize connection to the database using the URL in         config/config.js
var sequelize = config;

//Load all the models
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
      return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
 })
.forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
});

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
   if (db[modelName].associate) {
      db[modelName].associate(db);
   }
});

//Export the db Object
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

/models/nuke_users.js

```
/* jshint indent: 2 */

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
return sequelize.define('nuke_users', {
   user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
   },
   username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: "",
      references: {
         model: 'reps_table',
         key: 'PostName'
      }
   },
   user_email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: ""
   },
   user_avatar: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: ""
   },
   user_password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: ""
   }
 }, {
    tableName: 'nuke_users'
 });
};
```

/index.js

```
...
var models = require('./models/');
...
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your passport.js try to do it like

var models            = require('../models');
var User = models.nuke_users;

Comment: Okay, that worked.
How do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: Don't worry about it. I was too tired to write a properly answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `nuke_users` module is exporting a function that, when called, returns the `Model`. Because you aren't calling this function, it is not returning the `Model`, and thus the function you are looking for does not exist.

To call this exported function you would need to pass in the `sequelize` instance and `DataTypes`, as so:

```
var User = require('../models/nuke_users')(sequelize, DataTypes);
```

In your case you are using a loader in the `index.js` file, and it is exporting the `db` object which contains the models keyed by their name.

```
var models = require('../models'); // loads index.js
var User = models.nuke_user;       // the model keyed by its name
User.findOne(...);                 // search the model
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning the model, export it from `NukeUser.js`:

```
const NukeUser = sequelize.define('nuke_users', {
    // ...
});

module.exports = NukeUser;
```

Then in `index.js`:

```
const NukeUser = require('../models/NukeUser');
NukeUser.findAll() //.then() ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the models route in the collections, for example, in my case, I had `read()` as a method in my collections like that:

```
  async read(id) {
    try {
      if(id) {
        return await this.model.findOne({where: {id: id}});
      } else {
        return await this.model.findAll();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Error in reading data with the id: ${id}`);
    }
  }
```

So, `findAll()` wouldn't work. Instead, I used `read()`