# sequelize : cannot seed association values in DB table

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am trying to seed an association into my db using sequelize, the tables being: Users and Admins. For this I am relying on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48732223/sequelize-seed-with-associations) on the forum. so here is my seed:

```
'use strict';
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
module.exports = {
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [{
            firstName: 'someone',
            lastName: 'awesome',
            email: 'someone@somewhere.com',
            password: bcrypt.hashSync('helloWorld', 8),
            type: 'admin',
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date()
        }], {});

        const users = await queryInterface.sequelize.query(
            'SELECT id from Users;'
        );

        return await queryInterface.bulkInsert('Admins', [{
            id: users[0].id,
            phone: '+9999999999',
            status: true, createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date()
        }]);
    },
    down: async (queryInterface) => {
        await queryInterface.bulkDelete('Admins', null, {});
        await queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {});
    }
};
```

now, The data in user table is field up perfectly but the admin table remains empty

EDIT:

I tried to print out the users[0].id with the following code:

```
const users = await queryInterface.sequelize.query(
    "SELECT id from Users"
);

console.log(users[0].id)
```

the output was `undefined`

but the data was once again fed to the table! I know what is happening here, but don't know how to resolve!

P.S.
I also added await for the very first method of the up, but this changed nothing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not waiting for the users insert to end before querying for them, so this:

```
const users = await queryInterface.sequelize.query(
   'SELECT id from Users;'
);
```

Is empty, and this `users[0].id` must be throwing a type error

Adding an `await` to your first `queryInterface.bulkInsert` should fix that

```
await queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [{ // ...
```

Comment: Sorry, I was still edditing the soultion. Using `await` on the first `bulkInsert` should do it!

Comment: I did that, yet, the cli is responding with : `ERROR: Column 'id' cannot be null` ! but the data has been inserted into Users table

Comment: Maybe you could log the contents of `users` to see what that query is returning

Comment: You are almost there, with some more debugging and coding, your code will be doing what you expect. My hint is this: check the contents of `users`, not only `users[0].id`, good luck!

Comment: found the answer and posted it below on this thread! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

It took a while to figure this out, Thank you all.

literature I referred to:
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058479/sequelize-findall-is-not-a-function)
AND
[this part](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html) of official sequelize documentation

Here is the code that works:

```
'use strict';
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const models = require('../models');
const User = models.User;
module.exports = {
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [{
            firstName: 'aname',
            lastName: 'alastname',
            email: 'someemail@somewhere.com',
            password: bcrypt.hashSync('poochies', 8),
            type: 'admin',
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date()
        }], {});

        const user = await User.findOne({
            where: {
                type: 'admin',
                email: 'someemail@somewhere.com'
            },
        });

        return await queryInterface.bulkInsert('Admins', [{
            id: user.id,
            phone: '+999999999999',
            status: true,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date()
        }], {});
    },
    down: async (queryInterface) => {
        await queryInterface.bulkDelete('Admins', null, {});
        await queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {});
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `await` to the first `bulkInsert` method call and save its results into `userId` variable. The `bulkInsert` promise is resolved with the first ID of inserted sequence, so you can use it to create an admin like this:

```js
'use strict';
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = {
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        const userId = await queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [{
            firstName: 'someone',
            lastName: 'awesome',
            email: 'someone@somewhere.com',
            password: bcrypt.hashSync('helloWorld', 8),
            type: 'admin',
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date()
        }], {});

        return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Admins', [{
            id: userId,
            phone: '+9999999999',
            status: true,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date(),
        }]);
    },
    down: async (queryInterface) => {
        await queryInterface.bulkDelete('Admins', null, {});
        await queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {});
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can receive an array of the inserted objects and use it in the admin insertion.

```
let ids = await queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [{
                    firstName: 'someone',
                    lastName: 'awesome',
                    email: 'someone@somewhere.com',
                    password: bcrypt.hashSync('helloWorld', 8),
                    type: 'admin',
                    createdAt: new Date(),
                    updatedAt: new Date()
                }], { returning: ['id'] });

let adminId = ids[0];

//Insert admin
```

Comment: Be aware that the "returning" option is only available with Postgres SQL.